# Failed to bind to server ldap:// Error: Can't contact LDAP server

Tags: linux, redhat, openldap

We are running a Linux 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 kernel and keep seeing the following messages in /var/log/messages periodically showing up on our user space server. When the messages appear we also have users stating that they are unable to access network drive space.

```
 Nov  5 20:10:40 <server_name> smbd[15502]:   failed to bind to server ldap://<server-ip> with dn="cn=user,dc=some_domain,dc=some_domain,dc=some-domain" Error: Can't contact LDAP server
 Nov  5 20:10:40 <server_name> smbd[15502]:   #011(unknown)
 Nov  5 20:10:41 <server_name> smbd[15503]: [2013/11/05 20:10:41.146650,  0] lib/smbldap.c:1225(smbldap_connect_system)
 Nov  5 20:10:41 <server_name> smbd[15503]:   failed to bind to server ldap://<server-ip> with dn="cn=user,dc=some_domain,dc=some_domain,dc=some-domain" Error: Can't contact LDAP server
 Nov  5 20:10:41 <server_name> smbd[15503]:   #011(unknown)
 Nov  5 20:10:42 <server_name> smbd[1655]: [2013/11/05 20:10:42.868838,  0] lib/smbldap.c:1225(smbldap_connect_system)
 Nov  5 20:10:42 <server_name> smbd[1655]:   failed to bind to server ldap://<server-ip> with dn="cn=user,dc=some_domain,dc=some_domain,dc=some-domain" Error: Can't contact LDAP server
 Nov  5 20:10:42 <server_name> smbd[1655]:   #011(unknown)
 Nov  5 20:10:48 <server_name> smbd[15504]: [2013/11/05 20:10:48.531242,  0] lib/smbldap.c:1225(smbldap_connect_system)
 Nov  5 20:10:48 <server_name> smbd[15504]:   failed to bind to server ldap://<server-ip> with dn="cn=user,dc=some_domain,dc=some_domain,dc=some-domain" Error: Can't contact LDAP server
 Nov  5 20:10:48 <server_name> smbd[15504]:   #011(unknown)
```

Linux users are unable to authenticate, but windows users can.

None of our other linux servers are showing error messages like these. Not even our ldap server.

What should we look for in regards to the cause of these error and what can we do to resolve this issue? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---- Quick update -----

We have now discovered that we can resolve the authentication problems with the following command being ran on our server running ldap:

```
 service slapd restart
```

However, we still cannot determine what is causing this issue.

Comment: Could the problem be in DNS?  I wonder if restarting may have caused the connection attempt to be re-tried.  If it were DNS, success would be intermittent around the restarts.

Comment: @jcalfee314 We have not seen any problems related to DNS. Even during these outages we are able to resolve names of various servers. Thanks for the suggestion, though. We will look into it as a possibility. We have also noticed that just before these errors appear we get another kind of error stating: `Nov  7 11:24:30 <server-name> slapd[1796]: warning: cannot open /etc/hosts.allow: Too many open files
Nov  7 11:24:30 <server-name> slapd[1796]: warning: cannot open /etc/hosts.deny: Too many open files`

Comment: so I have increased the number of maximum open files in /proc/sys/fs/file-max in hopes of resolving our problem.

Comment: Has anyone seen an update for how to resolve this issue. We are having the exact same problem, but have already increased the max number of files. We are also not sure as to what is causing the issue. But running `service slapd restart` has seemed to resolve the problem for now!

Comment: Additional note, we have updated our kernel on this server as well to Linux 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64